# Grouping without duplicating supplier row

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Having trouble getting data from NorthWind using Linq-to-SQL from 3 tables:

1. `Suppliers`
2. `Products`
3. `Categories`

I would like to fetch the suppliers of all products which are in a category with `categoryId > 3`. The resultset would need 1 row per supplier, and then some child-set containing a row per product including the category info. The idea is that this resultset will be returned as a json value from an ajax call.

The following is the simplest version of my efforts so far:

```
from sups in Suppliers
join prods in Products on sups.SupplierID equals prods.SupplierID
join cats in Categories on prods.CategoryID equals cats.CategoryID
where ( cats.CategoryID > 3)

group sups by sups.SupplierID into g
select g
```

In LinqPad it looks like the resultset contains many duplicate suppliers.
Any thoughts?

EDITED:
Thanks to the answer of Adduci, i ended up with the following working LINQ statement:

```
from sups in Suppliers
join prods in Products on sups.SupplierID equals prods.SupplierID
join cats in Categories on prods.CategoryID equals cats.CategoryID
where cats.CategoryID > 3
group new { sups, prods, cats } by new { sups.SupplierID, sups.CompanyName } into g
select new 
{
  g.Key,
  ProductInfo = from x in g
                 select new
                 {
                    ProductProperty = x.prods.ProductName,
                    CategoryProperty = x.cats.CategoryName
                 }  
}
```

The extra `by new { sups.SupplierID, sups.CompanyName }`completes the resultset including supplier fields. Nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to group your 3 tables together using an anonymous class

```
group new { sups, prods, cats }
```

Instead of `select g` which is an (`IGrouping<...>`) you should explicitly define the properties you want like this:

```
from sups in Suppliers
join prods in Products on sups.SupplierID equals prods.SupplierID
join cats in Categories on prods.CategoryID equals cats.CategoryID
where cats.CategoryID > 3
group new { sups, prods, cats } by sups.SupplierID into g
select new 
{
  Supplier = g.Key,
  ProductInfo = from x in g
                 select new
                 {
                    ProductProperty = x.prods.Prop1,
                    CategoryProperty = x.cats.Prop1
                 }  
}
```

This way you will prevent returning unused information form the database

Comment: I see you've fixed the typo g.prods to x.prods. Thanks a lot!! Works perfect!

Comment: I just realised, there's one more issue with this: the supplier record info itself only contains the Key value and the productinfo ... can that be extended, with other supplier properties (ex CompanyName?)

Comment: @Paul0515 - Yes. You can add `CompanyName = g.FirstOrDefault().sups.CompanyName`or your way may even be better

Answer (score 1):

That's often the case when joining tables. You can usually fix that using `Distinct()`.

Something like this:

```
(from sups in Suppliers
join prods in Products on sups.SupplierID equals prods.SupplierID
join cats in Categories on prods.CategoryID equals cats.CategoryID
where ( cats.CategoryID > 3)
group sups by sups.SupplierID into g
select g).Distinct()
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, one of the issues was getting the properties of the product and the category on the same row as well ...